# Associated param not going through, but others will? Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Issue:** Specific record from associated model won't pass through on create, but others from the same associated model will....

**I have the following in my create for UserProducts:**

```
    def create
        @user_product = UserProduct.new(user_product_params)
        @product = Product.find_by(params[:product_id])
        @user = current_user
        @user_product.user_id = @user.id
        @user_product.country = @product.country
        @user_product.production_price = @product.price

    ...

    private
    ...
        def user_product_params
          params.require(:user_product).permit(:product_id, :color, :size, :production_price, {product_ids: []})
        end
```

**Models:**

**Product:**

`has_and_belongs_to_many :user_products`

**User Products:**

`has_and_belongs_to_many :products`

The issue I don't get is that `@user_product.country = @product.country` passes through to my models db perfectly fine.  But `@user_product.production_price = @product.price` won't.  Is there a possible interference?

Product model has a `t.string "price"`, and UserProduct has the `t.string "production_price"`

I attempted putting `.to_s` at the end of price, didn't work.  Tried putting `.to_i` at the end of price, didn't work either.

If I do `user_product.production_price = @product.price + 5` it will go through as `5`.  So, it's essentially saying production_price is nil when it isn't?

My biggest mind boggle is it passes country through but not price.

**In the CMD**. I see everything passing through, including :country without production_price.  No errors, or unpermitted params, etc.

Comment: Wow, I didn't have is whitelisted under the Product Controller.

Comment: Did you find a solution, yet?

Comment: Can you verify this in rails console? Load the specific Product, see what the price is, and assign it to a new UserProduct. Either that or use a breakpoint. Debugger and REPL are useful things in Ruby, not all languages have them ... might as well make use of them.

Comment: I'm confused. How did you get an object for this code `@product = Product.find_by(params[:product_id])` neither you mentioned the column name in the `find_by` method nor you used dynamic finder as `find_by_id`. How is that possible?